# Connecting multi threads to the local host at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to make 2 or more threads write through an output stream to a server-side application **at the same time** through java sockets.

but instead they are writing in a sequential order..

This MVCE acts the same..

**SERVER LISTENER**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

            Socket socket=null;
            try{
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5050);
                while (true) {

                    logger.warn("listening");
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    new TestingSession(socket).start();
                }
            }  catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

**SERVER THREAD:**

```
    class TestingSession extends Thread {
        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Class.class.getName());
        private Socket socket;
        TestingSession(Socket socket) {
                    try {
              
               DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                 this.socket = socket;
    
                while (!socket.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println(dataInputStream.readUTF());
               }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

**CLIENT MAIN**

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UpdateTest t1 = new UpdateTest();
        UpdateTest t2 = new UpdateTest();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        System.out.println("finished creation");

    }
}
```

**CLIENT THREAD**

```
public class UpdateTest extends Thread {

    public void run() {


        try {

           Socket socket;
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5050);
          DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
          for(int i=0; i <100;i++){
                Thread.sleep(50);
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(""+i);
                System.out.println(i);
          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

     }}
```

Client's output :

> Finished creation
>
> 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5

Servers output :

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 97 99 100
>
> -- exception socket closed.--
>
> listening
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 .. 99 100

Comment: The code you have shown us looks OK to me.  How are you starting these client/server programs?  Are you using two separate processes on your test system so they can run independently?

Comment: @markspace yes theyre 2 separate applications, i start the server's main method first then the clients one

Comment: @MarkRotteveel its not the statement.. and even if i removed System.out from the client application the server is still writing in sequential order

Comment: You implemented the while loop in the constructor of the ServerThread and not in the run that will run on background. There's an answer that also says that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have just messed up the class definition.  My IDE tells me that the instance variable `socket` in `TestingSession` is not used.  Then I noticed that you wrote your entire server "thread" in the constructor, causing `start()` to do nothing, and making your server execute only in one single thread.

Change this:

```
class TestingSession extends Thread {
   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Class.class.getName());

   private Socket socket;

   TestingSession( Socket socket ) {
      try {

         DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
         this.socket = socket;

         while( !socket.isClosed() ) {
            System.out.println( dataInputStream.readUTF() );
         }

      } catch( Exception e ) {
      }
   }

}
```

To this:

```
class TestingSession extends Thread {
   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Class.class.getName());

   private Socket socket;

   TestingSession( Socket socket ) {
         this.socket = socket;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      try {
         DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
         while( !socket.isClosed() ) {
            System.out.println( dataInputStream.readUTF() );
         }

      } catch( Exception e ) {
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: I had missed that entirely, but even better would be to not extend `Thread`, implement `Runnable` and construct a normal `Thread`.

Comment: And that's a great point.  Extending `Thread` is considered gauche these days, use `Runnable` or `Callable` (which would have prevented the OP from accidentally calling start()).

Comment: Thanks it worked :), and yea ill use Runnable from now on, i was just messing stuff up trying to fix this thing.. thanks :)

Comment: No worries, I probably wouldn't have noticed if it weren't for my IDE (solution: get a better IDE!).  But these "best practice" advice things like "don't extend Thread" are there for a reason and can help you avoid difficult to diagnose problems like this in the first place.

Comment: @user2962142 NetBeans

Comment: @markspace Huh? The OP is not accidentally calling `start`, and also Runnables still have constructors.